# Cannot get row_range in perl script

Tags: perl

My code doesn't seem to get row_range(). It shows an error which is:

> Can't locate object method "row_range" via package
>   "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet" at clamp_init_value.pl line 41.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

 my $filename = '../../doc/Book1.xls';
 my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
 my $workbook = $parser -> Parse( $filename);

 if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die "-E-: cannot parse <$filename>.\n";
 }

 for my $worksheet ( $workbook-> Worksheet( 'family pin list' ) ) {

    # Find out the worksheet ranges
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            # Return the cell object at $row and $col
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand slightly on [the answer from TFBW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650152/7231)...

The [Changes](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel) file for this module includes the following entry:

```
0.43 January 7 2009

    + Restructured and rewrote the main documentation. This is the start of
      a general refactoring. If you would like to keep up to date with it
      keep an eye on the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel Google Group.
      http://groups.google.com/group/spreadsheet-parseexcel

    + Added worksheets() Workbook method to iterate over the Worksheet objects.

    + Added unformatted() method to get a Cell's unformatted value.

    + Renamed public methods RowRange(), ColRange() and Cell() to row_range(),
      col_range() and get_cell(). Old methods are still available.

    ! Turned on compatibility_mode() by default in SaveParser to avoid SP3
      problems.

    ! Fixed minor SaveParser bug with font rotation.
      http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=41626
```

So if you have a version of the module that is older than version 0.43, then the method you want is called `RowRange()`. You can find the version of the module that you have installed by typing this at a command line prompt:

```
perl -MSpreadsheet::ParseExcel -le'print $Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::VERSION'
```

If you do have a version of the module that is over ten years old, then I strongly recommend updating it.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet is it? Those methods used to be named RowRange() ColRange() and Cell() in the past. See https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel